# how create stepper widget in flutter with more than 20 steps?

Tags: flutter, stepper

how create stepper widget in flutter with more than 20 steps ?
like below image:
[image]

i tried normal stepper widget and its ok for small steps
but for big steps it will be messy
im looking a way to show it better like attached image

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  List<Step> stepList() => [
        const Step(
            title: Text('step 1'),
            content: Center(
              child: Text('step 1'),
            )),
        const Step(
            title: Text('step 2'),
            content: Center(
              child: Text('step 2'),
            )),
        const Step(
            title: Text('step 3'),
            content: Center(
              child: Text('step 3'),
            )),
        const Step(
            title: Text('step 4'),
            content: Center(
              child: Text('step 4'),
            )),
        const Step(
            title: Text('step 5'),
            content: Center(
              child: Text('step 5'),
            )),
        const Step(
            title: Text('step 6'),
            content: Center(
              child: Text('step 6'),
            )),
        const Step(
            title: Text('step 7'),
            content: Center(
              child: Text('step 7'),
            )),
        const Step(
            title: Text('step 8'),
            content: Center(
              child: Text('step 8'),
            )),
        const Step(
            title: Text('step 9'),
            content: Center(
              child: Text('step 9'),
            )),
      ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          title: const Text(
            'test',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),

        // Here we have initialized the stepper widget
        body: Stepper(
          type: StepperType.horizontal,
          steps: stepList(),
        ));
    ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal listView for this. I am using [scroll_to_index](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index) to make it easier on scroll/changing index.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int totalSteps = 24;
  int activeStep = 0;
  List<Widget> get stepList => [
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++)
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              onTap(i);
            },
            child: AutoScrollTag(
              controller: _scrollController,
              index: i,
              key: ValueKey(i),
              child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: i == activeStep ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Text("$i")),
            ),
          )
      ];

  final AutoScrollController _scrollController = AutoScrollController(
    axis: Axis.horizontal,
  );

  void goTo(int step) async {
    setState(() => activeStep = step);
    _scrollController.scrollToIndex(step, preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.middle);

    //! not working as expected,need to calculate the offset
    // final gap = 50.0 + 25 + 5; // 50 width of stepper , 50 gap between each stepper
    // final offset = step * gap;
    // _scrollController.animateTo(
    //   offset,
    //   duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    //   curve: Curves.easeIn,
    // );
  }

  _moveNext() {
    activeStep + 1 < totalSteps ? goTo(activeStep + 1) : null;
  }

  _previous() {
    activeStep - 1 < 0 ? null : goTo(activeStep - 1);
  }

  void onTap(int index) {
    activeStep = index;
    setState(() {});
    goTo(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        title: const Text(
          'test',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),

      // Here we have initialized the stepper widget
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: _previous,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => stepList[index],
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Align(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 10,
                          width: 50,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    itemCount: totalSteps,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(onPressed: _moveNext, icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```